# Finder shows incorrect application icon for VMware Fusion

Tags: macos, applications, icon

The VMware Fusion app (via Finder) is showing the wrong (After Effects) icon in the Application list.

See the selected line in my list of applications below:

[image]

I’m on macOS Mojave 10.14.

**How can I correct this so that the correct icon is shown for the VMware Fusion app?**

Comment: If you go to your applications folder in a normal finder window, is the icon correct? Is the icon correct in the dock when opening VMware Fusion?

Comment: I'm seeing the same, It shows a text edit icon instead of the fusion icon. However, launchpad shows the correct icon.